# Firebug Breakpoint not captured in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, firebug, breakpoints

I have a valid  break point in javascript, but the firebug is showing that as `(?)` left panel. Whats the error.

However the code is working fine in jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/kcEjN/
I have check and jquery is loaded correctly.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Enclosing with

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#abc").click(function() { 
                   alert("I am alteast here");
           document.write("<p>I am inside script avaScript</p>");
        } );

});
```

solved the issue.

Comment: That's a good idea, but that doesn't really make sense - window load should always be after DOMContentLoaded.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Firebug to debug this - I tested in the JSFiddle, and what you want to do works with the built in debugger:

[image]

It could be that Firebug is getting confused about references, maybe using previously loaded frame's context?

Comment: Why the downvote - in what version of firefox does this break?